# RGB-Depth Datasets for Images and Videos

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset

I'm looking for RGB-D (D is depth) datasets of images and videos for object detection and recognition tasks similar to the ones provided by PASCAL VOC or ILSVRC (but augmented with depth data).

Comment: The nyu datasets (http://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/) have depth maps + scene segmentation (pixel-wise). There is also a depthmap if I rememer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A great list of RGBD datasets can be found here : http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Firman/RGBDdatasets/